# Firefox extension to override website font preferences on individual websites?

Tags: firefox, font-utility

Is there such a thing as a Firefox extension to override a website's preferred fonts, able to be used selectively on individual websites?

(Preferably for Firefox 52 ESR at present, but also for Firefox Quantum in the future)

I know that it is possible to untick *"Allow pages to choose their own fonts"* in: **Preferences » Content » Fonts » Advanced**, but this is an all-or-nothing setting, and makes all sites use only your preferred fonts, and so losing much of the design theme of many sites.

Unfortunately, there are some websites which do not design their stylesheets very well to work properly on all platforms, and often, especially when browsing on Linux, the site's "preferred" fonts can be quite inelegant or less readable when you visit that particular website. For such sites (and only for those individual sites, on a site by site basis), it would be useful to be able to override their font preferences to use your own font choice(s) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stylus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/) is the alternative without tracking.
So you can customize the skin of any website.

Answer (score 0):

The [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/stylish/) extension allows you to customize any website and save that preferences.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds similar to (if not rather more powerful than) what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, their [privacy policy](https://userstyles.org/login/policy) sounds like they spy on your every web request (_and data sent in response_), which sounds very worrying to me.

Comment: You are right. Here there is several but I don't know them https://alternativeto.net/software/stylish/

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I did not know about the _alternative.to_ website, very useful! Via that website, I found [Stylus](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/styl-us/) which is a fork of Stylish with no tracking. (Feel free to post this as an answer yourself if you want, and I will credit you for pointing me in the right direction).